# Angular CDK Overlay: make overlay add to the height

Tags: angular, overlay, angular-cdk

Presently if I create overlay that is sticking outsize of the window it is cutoff. How can I configure it so if say my overlay is longer then space below trigger it will increase body height so i can scroll to the bottom of overlay.
[image]

Comment: I'm also struggling on this too. Were you ever able to find an answer?